# Overriding content of output input file from second line in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am copying content of my input file to a output file, I am able to override current data of output file using set-content but I don't want to override the headers. Headers should remain as it is and input file content should be added after second line. Also once I repeat the same activity , it should add the output after second line and previous data should be override excluding headers.
How we can achieve this?

I am using below code but its appending content of $destRoot1 to $destRoot2.
It should override existing content excluding first line(headers).

```
Add-Content -Path $destRoot2 "`n"
Get-content -Path $destRoot1 | Add-Content -Path $destRoot2 -Encoding UTF8
((Get-Content -Path $destRoot2) -notmatch '^\s*$' )| Select-Object -Unique |             
Set-Content -Path $destRoot2 -Encoding UTF8
Clear-Content $destRoot1
```

destroot1 is like below

```
Warmup,18/02/2021 05:00:00,18/02/2021 05:06:04,Success
root_Job_1,02/02/2021 06:27:34,02/02/2021 06:28:37,Failure
root_Job_2,02/02/2021 06:27:34,02/02/2021 06:28:16,Success
root_Job_3,02/02/2021 06:27:34,02/02/2021 06:41:58,Success
root_Job_4,02/02/2021 06:38:00,02/02/2021 06:38:01,Failure
root_Job_1,02/02/2021 06:27:34,02/02/2021 06:30:11,Failure
```

destroot2 will only contain headers :

```
job_name,start_time,end_time,status
```

I need to append the data of destroot1 to destroot2  after headings as well as once I run script again, it should remove the data after headings and updated data from destroot1

Comment: What have you tried? Why tag all possible PowerShell versions? Where are the examples?

Comment: @Theo Updated the details

Comment: Try changing to `Add-Content  -Path $destRoot2 -Encoding UTF8` (Set-Content overwrites all while Add-Content well... it **adds** lines)

Comment: @Theo Did that but Its appending the output every time I run the code. It should append as well as override. First line should remain same. after that it should override the content.

Comment: Without examples this would be a guessing game.. Please add examples of the files in destroot1 and 2